# My asp.net site suddenly stop working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have  a asp.net MVC 4 that earlier works fine. Now when I run it I got error like

```
A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup

Source Error:


Line 291:            using (MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(Globals.CONNSTRING))
Line 292:            {
Line 293:                cnn.Open();
Line 294:
Line 295:                using (MySqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
```

I upload it on server and it's make crash of IIS on server. now every site on server is not working. can someone please tell me how to fix it?

This exception I got on my computer. When I visit to my site I see

```
Service Unavailable

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
```

Comment: Can you able to connect to your database? You could make sure database is still up.

Comment: Service unavailable. I.E. the Service that runs the site is not running... the Application Pool.

Comment: just check connection string , issue may be related to connection  with `MySql`. And also make sure that `MySql` is running on the port 3306.

Comment: @ArjunVachhani I have running everything. I just write a wrong statement and mistakenly it's going upload to server on same time.

Answer (score 0):

Your database lookup can't be found...check the connection strings and make sure each part you have deployed shares the same connection logic :)

Comment: Service Unavailable means the App pool is down. It doesn't even get to the point where code executes.